# How to retrieve the Entry widget text from a class in Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, widget

I've been stuck here for quite a while, i have an entry widget declared inside a class in a file, and i wanna retrieve the entered text from outside the class and perhaps from a seperate file inside a function that prints the text, i have made a short example of the issue:

```
from tkinter import *

class main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
    def entry(self, entry_widget, width, text):
        self.width = width
        self.text = text
        self.entry_widget = Entry(self.master, width = self.width, textvariable = self.text)
        self.entry_widget.pack()
    def buttons(self, button_widget, width, height, text):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.button_widget = Button(self.master, width = self.width, height = self.height, text = self.text, command = get_value)
        self.button_widget.pack()


root = Tk()
my_text = StringVar()
obj = main(root)
obj.entry("field", 60, my_text)

def get_value():
    my_text = entry.get()
    print(my_text)

obj.buttons("my_button", 30,20,"click")


root.mainloop()
```

This could be totally wrong, for i have no clue how to read the text from an entry widget in Tkinter

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special or unique to tkinter that you have to do. You just need a reference to the object so that you can call methods on it. In your case, the entry widget is the `entry_widget` attribute on `obj`.

```
def get_value():
    my_text = obj.entry_widget.get()
    print(my_text)
```